# Find a maximal ideal which contains a given ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the ideal $I = (xyz, x^2+y^2+z^2)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z],$ I need to find a maximal ideal $J \neq (x,y,z)$ which contains $I$ as a proper subset. Given that any maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ has the form $(x-\alpha,x-\beta, z-\gamma)$ with $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{C}.$ I tried to find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that any generator in $I$ will be represented as a linear combination of the generators of $J$ and elements of the ring. Nevertheless, I can not find such a set. It makes me have some doubt in the form I suppose the maximal ideal $J$ should have. I also want to find a maximal ideal in the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/I.$ Can somebody help me out or provide a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The ideal $(x-\alpha, y-\beta, z-\gamma)$ is the same as $\{f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]: f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=0\}$. It's not difficult to find some $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ such that the generators of $I$ all vanish at this point.

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ contains $(xyz,x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry, I want $J \neq (x,y,z).$ I will correct it in the post.

Comment: @user996159 My comment is still relevant. Find some other point other than $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @Mark. Many thanks. Your suggestion is what I am trying to do right now. One of the constants has to be $0$ in order to get the first generator vanish.

Comment: @user996159 Yes, take $x=0$. Then find some nonzero $y,z$ such that $y^2+z^2=0$.

Comment: So, a solution is then, $(x,y-i,z-1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that because $xyz \in J$, that $x\in J$, $y\in J$, or $z\in J$. Assume $x \in J$. Then, $x^2+y^2+z^2\in J$ and $x^2\in J$, so $y^2+z^2 \in J$. Can you find such a $J$ now?

Once such a $J$ is obtained, recall that maximal ideals of a quotient ring $R/I$ are exactly the images of maximal ideals from $R$. So, if you pick $J=(x,y-i,z-1)$, then a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/I$ could be taken to be $J/I = (x+I,y-i+I,z-1+I) \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/I$.

Comment: Notice $y^2+z^2 = (y-iz)(y+iz)$. As in your comment above, if we set $z=1$ then $y=i$ or $y=-i$ are both solutions, which give maximal ideals $J_1 = (x,y-i,z-1)$ and $J_2=(x,y+i,z-1)$ as options. For a different set of maximal ideals, you can set $z=i$ to get $y^2-1=(y+1)(y-1)$, which gives $J_3 = (x,y-1,z-i)$ and $J_4=(x,y+1,z-i)$ as options. You can also try $z=-i$, $z=2i$, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Following your suggestion, one gets, $(y-i)(y+i) + (z-1)(z+1) = y^2+z^2.$ Thus, $J = (x,y-i, z-1).$

Comment: I don't think that factorization works. $(y-i)(y+1)=y^2+(1-i)y-i$ and that middle term is not cancelled in the other product.

Comment: How about the question I also posted, in finding a maximal ideal in the residual ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/I$ ? Do you have there any suggestion ?

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Are you using the correspondence theorem in your argument ? How can one check that that ideal in the quotient space is maximal ?

Comment: Yes. The correspondence theorem states that the (prime/maximal) ideals in a ring $R/I$ are exactly the images of (prime/maximal) ideals in $R$ under the canonical projection map $R\rightarrow R/I$ given by $r\mapsto r+I$.